# Translation Manager - Publish to Preview

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager

The new Publish to Preview functionality in SDL Web 8.5:

[image]

Would this publish minor versions of content?

Comment: I think so - if the target allows for items in a given approval status (not sure which one) to be published, it will use the "in-workflow" version of the item, i.e., the one coming from translation.

Comment: In my case it would go to a Preview target which has no minimum approval - so I should expect the "in-workflow" version to be published?

Comment: Yes it should be published to targets without minimum approval status.

Comment: Cheers - update as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process will use workflow approval status for the content (don't know which one by heart), and therefore the Preview/Staging target that you're publishing to must allow content with that approval status to be published.

If your target has no minimum approval status set, then the content will be published to the Preview/Staging target.